# How to create a filter using a JSON array in Spring Boot

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, filter

I am creating a web aplication using Angular 8 for the frontend, and Spring Boot for the backend (I am quite new to SpringBoot programming)

I have a table with a list of "protocols" and a checkbox filter above it. Here is a screenshot of the webpage: [image]

When I click "Apply Filters" button, it generates a JSON array like this:

```
[{subject_id:[2,3]},{scenario_id:[2]},{algorithms_id:[2]}]
```

Now, in the backend, I want to create a filter using this JSON array, so that it returns only the corresponding protocols. I guess I have to use a Query functionality and @GetMapping in java SpringBoot. But I don't know how to specify which JSON item to use for each attribute of "protocol". If you could give me some advice on how to do this, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a Java class - Filter.java with fields :

```
private List<String> subject_id=new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> scenario_id=new ArrayList<>();
private List<String> algorithms_id=new ArrayList<>();
```

and then write a POST controller with a RequestBody like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myapi", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getResultsByFilter(
            @RequestBody(required = true) List<Filter> filters)
```

this way you can get the filter in the request body and then process it as per your business logic to return results as you want them.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, sorry for answering late, I have problems with my DB, I will try your solution once I solve my DB issue